Update database docker
My api and database are other docker containers. I managed to make  a migration but update database doesn't work, becouse can't connect to database, becouse dont know password for 'sa' user. I used CLI commands.
In my app I have configured connection using variables in docker-compose file and Program.cs.
So far, what I did was to run containers (docker-compose up) from VisualStudio terminal and create migrations from an other terminal. How can i update database in this situation?
Link to commit is below:
https://github.com/Arachnacein/App/tree/feature/add-categorization-of-transaction
I tried use commands inside of container.
I tried use "RUN dotnet ef database update" in Dockerfile. Error was "An error occurred using the connection to database 'master' on server ''."

Usually migrations are run programmatically during application startup, using credentials provided from environment.  Probably you have connectivity problem, what is weird.

Is sql-server container running? What  doesdocker ps command show? Last time i was playing with SQLServer in containers it was nasty to bootstrap.

Btw, no need to call .AddEnvironmentVariables(); in .NET8, this configuration provider comes out-of-the-box here.

becouse dont know password for 'sa' user VS var db_password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("db_password");

This code in Program.cs and removed dbCreator from dbContext.cs solved my problem.
//automiatic migrations
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TransactionDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
}

